# Docker container throws error with python2.7

Tags: docker, python-2.7

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20 AS node-stage
RUN npm install -g ts-node

#FROM python:3.11
FROM python:2.7
COPY --from=node-stage . .
```

It throws the following error:

```
=> ERROR [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=node-stage . .                                                                                                        0.1s
------
 > [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=node-stage . .:
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     #FROM python:3.11
   5 |     FROM python:2.7
   6 | >>> COPY --from=node-stage . .
   7 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/uv99gn6qcbue5nvqe07ebh8nb/merged/bin with file
```

With python3, the code worked fine. Why am I having this error?

I tried adding --no-cache to build command, it didn't help.

UPD: I replaced the last command with

```
COPY --from=node-stage /usr/local/bin/ts-node /usr/local/bin/ts-node
```

per ChatGPT's suggestion, and it solved the issue. I still don't understand why, though.

Comment: Python 2.7 hasn't been supported in years, can you explain why you need it?

Comment: I want to submit a bug for this bounty; the bug is in an old library that uses python2.7. https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/JKtM5C2TTwhzoHFRB/send-us-example-gnarly-bugs

Answer (score 0):

If it really works that way, with `COPY --from=node-stage . .` you are trying to copy literally everything from the `node-stage` build stage, root and all, so no wonder it fails. If you wanted to have really everything, then don't use build stages at all.

The updated command you specified `COPY --from=node-stage /usr/local/bin/ts-node /usr/local/bin/ts-node` is more sane, since it specifices a single folder to be copied over.

See https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/ for mor information about multistage builds.